# ComputerCraft Run Chat Command

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft, minecraft-commands

I host a server and I was wondering: is there any way to run chat commands through ComputerCraft? I want to be able to run `/tps` through the ComputerCraft terminal and then have it print out the TPS. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can use this thing called the Chat Box.

http://ftbwiki.org/Chat_Box

It's not part of the default Computercraft, however. It is part of the Misc Peripherals mod I believe.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Computercraft 1.7 there is a new type of computer, the Command Computer. It allows the user to run commands the same way as `shell.run("mkdir", "foo")`. It can only be obtained by ops, and can only directly be controlled (we are talking without using rednet and such) by ops

- `commands.exec(string command) -- Runs and outputs command output in chat.`
- `commands.execAsync(string command) -- Quietly runs command without output.`

Here is the wiki page:

[Commands (API)](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Commands_(API))

But if we are talking 1.6.4 (Which almost all modpacks use) there is no "stock" version of doing that.

Hope it helps /Tyrerexus